# Could not read data while printing image - GCP

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-print

I'm not able to print a `base64` encoded image with `GCP`.

This is what I'm using :

```
var data = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD//gBERmlsZSBzb3VyY ....";

var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
gadget.setPrintButton(cloudprint.Gadget.createDefaultPrintButton("gcpPrint"));
gadget.setPrintDocument("image/jpeg", "JPG Image", data, "base64");
gadget.openPrintDialog();
```

As  mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget). But `GCP` could not read data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to remove :

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,
```

from the `base64` string.